# QML Rectangle button highlight delay

Tags: c++, qt, qml, delay, highlight

I have a list of buttons that i want to highlight separately when a user presses it until it is released.

The problem with this is that when you scroll through the list, the first button you touch will highlight even though u touched it for a millisecond. It does not look nice so i want to add a delay for the highlight animation to occur.

a little delay before the highlight animation happens would probably fix this cosmetic issue i presume.

**How do i add a delay to a highlight animation?**

I have been trying something like:

```
Rectangle {
    id: folderButton    
    property bool pressed: false
    signal clicked

    height: mainWindoww.height * 0.1
    width: parent.width
    color: pressed ? "lightgrey" : "white"

    function release() {
        autoRepeatClicks.stop()
        folderButton.pressed = false
    }

    SequentialAnimation on pressed {
        id: autoRepeatClicks
        running: false

        PropertyAction { target: folderButton; property: "pressed"; value: true }
        ScriptAction { script: folderButton.clicked() }
        PauseAnimation { duration: 1000 }

        SequentialAnimation {
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            ScriptAction { script: folderButton.clicked() }
            PauseAnimation { duration: 500 }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: autoRepeatClicks.start()
        onReleased: folderButton.release()
        onCanceled: folderButton.release()
    }
}
```

but it seems as if this code does not add any kind of time difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Timer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html) to achieve this. For instance, you can do:

```
Item {
    Timer {
        interval: 500;
        running: true;
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: time.text = Date().toString()
    }

    Text { id: time }
}
```

Comment: If someone provided an answer to your question it is helpful for other people looking at your question who might have the same problem if there's an accepted answer. You can accept an answer by clicking the tick below the voting options.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to animate color property, try something like:

`Behavior on color { ColorAnimation { duration: 1000 } }`

Comment: Nope, it is not about the color change. I want to delay the color change so that it does not occur immediately as soon as it is touched. This makes scrolling look ugly because you see a button flashing every time you scroll